# difference between these 2 loops

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm stuyding Python 3 by myself and have a question that I don't understand about these two loops:

```
a = [1,2,3,4,5]

for count,item in enumerate(a):
    if count >= 3:
        print(item)
# output: [4,5]


for count,item in enumerate(a):
    if count >= 3:
        print(item)
    else:
        break
# shows me nothing
```

What's the difference between these?

The only difference is `else` and `break`, and one shows me what I want while the other doesn't. Why does only the first one work?

Comment: do you know what `break` does? if so, what is your problem? if not then google it, e.g. https://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/python_break_statement.htm

Comment: Yes, the only differences are the `else` and `break`. They are the reason that nothing is printed. Maybe you meant `pass` instead of `break` (although that would be pretty pointless)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**break** statement ends the loop.

When count=0, it goes to `else`. Then, the for loop ends and it prints nothing.

Let's change your code a little bit for a better understanding:

```
l = [a, b, c, d, e]
for count,item in enumerate(l):
    if count >= 3:
        print(item)
for count,item in enumerate(l):
    if count >= 3:
        print(item)
    else:
        break
```

Here is the steps of **the first loop**:

count=0, item=a

count=1, item=b

count=2, item=c

count=3, item=d => print(d)

count=4, item=e => print(e)

Here is the steps of **the second loop**:

count=0, item=a => else => break